# Filter out transactions occurring within a timeframe with the same amount

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply some filtering on a data frame using pandas.
Basically my data frame has the following column:

- ID - The row id of the transaction
- Timestamp - object was transformed to datetime format
- Amount - float

The data frame consists of more than 100k transactions. I want to filter out all of transactions that have the same amount, and occur within a minute of each other. In a single minute I can have 10 transactions, and all of the 10 will be filtered out (These transactions will be moved to a new data frame called Duplicates for example).

```
ID      TMSP              amount  
0     2019-01-01 00:01:11  89 
1     2019-01-01 00:01:17  89  
2     2019-01-01 00:02:49  238  
3     2019-01-01 00:03:13  238  
7     2019-01-01 00:08:46  117
```

As an example in the above records, we will be filtering out the first four records.

Logically we have to create a loop, go through the records (i+1 and i), compare the amount and time difference, and if it matches the conditions, the i+1 row will be moved to the new data frame. Is there any other methods that we can use in pandas that could do some sort of grouping based on several conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to DataScience Exchange. It would be good to have more data to explore the solution, but I've came up with one and it might work as intended.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 7],
    "time": [pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01 00:01:11"),
             pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01 00:01:17"),
             pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01 00:02:49"),
             pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01 00:03:13"),
             pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01 00:08:46")
            ],
    "amount": [89, 89, 238, 238, 117]
}

df_dup = (
    df
    .groupby("amount")
    .agg({"time": ["max", "min"], "id": list})
    .assign(time_diff=lambda df: df["time"]["max"] - df["time"]["min"],
           time_diff_in_seconds=lambda df: df["time_diff"].apply(lambda x: x.seconds),
           n_ids=lambda df: df["id"]["list"].apply(lambda x: len(x))
           )
    .loc[lambda df: (df["time_diff_in_seconds"] <= 60) & (df["n_ids"] > 1)]
)

ids_to_filter_out = df_dup["id"]["list"].explode().values.tolist()
```

Basically, I grouped data by amount, calculated min and max times and created a column called `time_diff_in_seconds` to see if these duplicates are in a range of less than one minute. I also calculated the number of ids to get only duplicated values.

The code could be improved for readability, however I would like to check with you if there are duplicated samples with more than one minute of difference between min and max and if they should be excluded as well, so a case such as:

```
ID      TMSP              amount  
0     2019-01-01 00:01:11  89 
1     2019-01-01 00:01:17  89
2     2019-01-01 00:03:17  89
3     2019-01-01 00:02:49  238  
4     2019-01-01 00:03:13  238  
7     2019-01-01 00:08:46  117
```

Is there cases such that? In this scenario, should we remove only ids 1 and 2?

Comment: This is what I needed thank you for your help - I was able to do it through the traditional if/else loop however both methods are working now